# deriving from a template

Tags: c++, templates, derived

I'm stuck on the following and could use some help:

```
typedef unsigned short USHORT;

template <typename DataType>
class Primative
{
protected:
    DataType m_dtValue;
public:
    Primative() : m_dtValue(0) {}

    DataType operator=(const DataType c_dtValue) { return m_dtValue = c_dtValue; }
    DataType Set(const DataType c_dtValue){ return m_dtValue = c_dtValue; }
};

typedef Primative<USHORT> PrimativeUS;

class Evolved : public PrimativeUS
{
public:
    Evolved() {}
};

int main()
{
    PrimativeUS prim;
    prim = 4;

    Evolved evo;
    evo.Set(5);  // good
    evo = USHORT(5); // error, no operator found which takes a right-hand operator...
}
```

It looks like the derived class is not getting the overloaded operator

Comment: I forgot to include that calling **evo.Set(5)** works

Comment: You've asked questions but not accepted answer for even one. Disappointing!

Comment: please indicate your acceptance of the answers to your previous questions. Please upvote any answer that helped you, and accept the answer that you find most helpful. More information and instructions are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: +1 for including a Short, Self-contained, Complete Example. (see http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class Evolved : public PrimativeUS
{
public:
  using PrimativeUS::operator=;
  Evolved() {}
};
```

The implicit `Evolved::operator=(const Evovled&)` that is provided for you hides all instances of `operator=` present in the base class. (This is true of any method - methods of derived classes hide similarly-named methods of base class, even if the signatures don't match.)

Comment: +1 I didn't know the implicit `operator=` hid explicit parent assignment operators.

Comment: Thanks; I also did not know that implicit `operator=` was hidden, and this solution works.

Comment: @kberson, I'm glad this solution works for you. Would you please upvote and accept the answers to this and your previous questions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your function declaration slightly:

```
DataType operator=(const DataType& c_dtValue) { return m_dtValue = c_dtValue; }
DataType Set(const DataType& c_dtValue){ return m_dtValue = c_dtValue; }
```

Note that a & (reference) sign is needed for operator overloading.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem -- the program still fails to compile.

Comment: Rob is correct, the program still fails to compile with the same error